# Why is Magento 1.9.2 not sending email after invoice created, but is sending an order email?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I know that there are a lot of issues on the new Magento version that have to do with configuring the cron for send the emails. These are configured and working: the order emails are sending.

But, don't know why, the **invoice is created**, and the status is Payed, **BUT the invoice email is not sent**.

I´m using the Braintree payments, but they don't know whats happen.
there I can't see any error on the PHP log.

Is there some trick for force to send this email?

Comment: How is the invoice being created?

Comment: When get the Ok on the checkout, the Magento default

Answer (score -1):

Here are some possibilities:

1. Are you using any free email extensions to send email?
   If yes then try to disable it.
2. Are you overriding any email class OR functionality? Check in that
   file too i.e.: `Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template` Class (send method).
3. Check your back-end settings.
4. Try to disable any email related extensions.